# JSON Jackson not ignoring null fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a POJO and Im trying to exclude null fields by using the `Include.NOT_EMPTY` annotation in the following manner.

**Updated with Complete code**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Items {

    /**
* 
*/
    @JsonProperty("items")
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties =
            new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *         The items
     */
    @JsonProperty("items")
    public List<item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param items
     *            The items
     */
    @JsonProperty("items")
    public void setitems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
  }
```

However,when I print out the JSON, I get a response in the following manner.

```
 {    "items": [
            {...}],

        "additionalProperties": { } // I expect this to be removed.
    }
```

Any idea what Im doing wrong here?
I'm using Jackson-core 2.1.1 if that matters.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. If I create a `new Items()` and serialize that directly, the JSON generated is `{}`.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I have already checked the the linked question and it does NOT help.

Comment: Please give us a complete example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Ive updated the entire POJO.

Comment: I'd like you to also post the code you use to serialize an instance, the actual output and the output you'd like to get.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't see a problem. I did `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new Items());` and it produces `{}`. Where do you see `"additionalProperties": { }`?

Comment: code posted works as desired, it is a duplicate, you re doing something wrong that is not indicated in the code posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add it on the Class level 
`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)`

The following piece of code works fine for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    String [] characteristics = new String[]{};
    Employee emp = new Employee("John", "20", "Male", characteristics);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_EMPTY);
    mapper.writeValue(System.out, emp);
}
class Employee {
    String name;
    String age;
    String gender;
    String [] characteristics;
    //setters and getters
    }
```

Output : `{"name":"John","age":"20","gender":"Male"}`

Comment: @KodeSeeker Use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) instead of @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)

Comment: @VVK. NON_NULL is a subset of NON_EMPTY http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.Inclusion.html#NON_EMPTY

Comment: @KodeSeeker yep...I used `NON_EMPTY` because I had an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your code like additionalProperties setter and property as below and use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) at class level

```
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = null;

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    if(additionalProperties == null)
        additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work either.